# cache "ways_of_associativity"

Tags: linux, caching

on linux system, in the directory /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index0/
what is the meaning of "ways_of_associativity" ?
Do somebody know the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Cache associativity is a way to decrease cache misses in exchange of lookup time. It is a trade-off.
[Associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Associativity)

Comment: Thanks Arkaitz. But that's not exactly what I asked for. I wanted to know the meaning of the file "ways_of_associativity". Now I have the answer. It's the number of subsets in the related cache memory.